# How to Grouping and take operations with vue.js loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this year-month-value array with data from gsheet:

```
2019 - Mar - 3
2019 - Mar - 1
2019 - Feb - 1
2019 - Feb - 1
2019 - Feb - 1
2019 - Feb - 1
2019 - Feb - 3
2019 - Feb -
2019 - Feb - 2
2019 - Feb - 1
2019 - Feb - 1
2019 - Jan - 1
2019 - Jan - 1
2019 - Jan - 1
2019 - Jan - 1
```

I want to sum the total values for each month like this:

```
2019 - Mar - 4
2019 - Feb - 11
2019 - Jan - 4
```

This is my code now:

```html
<div class="row" id="list">
  <div v-for="entry in entries" v-if="entry.gsx$regionofincident.$t === 'Mediterranean'">
    <span>{{entry.gsx$reportedyear.$t}} - {{entry.gsx$reportedmonth.$t}} - {{entry.gsx$numberdead.$t}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I sum the monthly values? Where do I do the operations? In `js` or `html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) to filter the Mediterranean items, and then use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to tally the results:

```js
computed: {
  medEntries() {
    const tally = this.entries
      // only process Mediterranean items
      .filter(entry => entry.gsx$regionofincident.$t === 'Mediterranean')

      // tally results
      .reduce((obj, entry) => {
        const key = entry.gsx$reportedyear.$t + entry.gsx$reportedmonth.$t
        const val = obj[key]
        const numDead = Number(entry.gsx$numberdead.$t || 0)

        if (val) {
          val.gsx$numberdead.$t = Number(val.gsx$numberdead.$t) + numDead
        } else {
          obj[key] = entry
        }
        return obj
      }, {})

    return Object.values(tally)
  }
}
```

Then replace `entries` in your template with the computed property name (`medEntries`):

```html
<div v-for="entry in medEntries">...</div>
```

```js
const entry = (year, month, numDead) => ({
  gsx$regionofincident: { $t : 'Mediterranean' },
  gsx$reportedmonth: { $t: month },
  gsx$reportedyear: { $t: year },
  gsx$numberdead: { $t: numDead },
})

const entries = [
  entry('2019', 'Mar', '3'),
  entry('2019', 'Mar', '1'),
  entry('2019', 'Feb', '1'),
  entry('2019', 'Feb', '1'),
  entry('2019', 'Feb', '1'),
  entry('2019', 'Feb', '1'),
  entry('2019', 'Feb', '3'),
  entry('2019', 'Feb'),
  entry('2019', 'Feb', '2'),
  entry('2019', 'Feb', '1'),
  entry('2019', 'Feb', '1'),
  entry('2019', 'Jan', '1'),
  entry('2019', 'Jan', '1'),
  entry('2019', 'Jan', '1'),
  entry('2019', 'Jan', '1'),
]

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      entries
    }
  },
  computed: {
    medEntries() {
      const tally = this.entries
        .filter(entry => entry.gsx$regionofincident.$t === 'Mediterranean')
        .reduce((obj, entry) => {
          const key = entry.gsx$reportedyear.$t + entry.gsx$reportedmonth.$t
          const val = obj[key]
          const numDead = Number(entry.gsx$numberdead.$t || 0)

          if (val) {
            val.gsx$numberdead.$t = Number(val.gsx$numberdead.$t) + numDead
          } else {
            obj[key] = entry
          }
          return obj
        }, {})

      return Object.values(tally)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="entry in medEntries">
    <span>{{entry.gsx$reportedyear.$t}} - {{entry.gsx$reportedmonth.$t}} - {{entry.gsx$numberdead.$t}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Tony. My entries coming from gsheet and I don't know how integrate your code with mine. I update the code above

Comment: @user2208245 You should already have a data property named `entries` (based on the code in the question). You just need to copy the `computed` and template changes from my answer. No need to copy my data-setup code (i.e., don't copy `const entry` or `const entries[]`).

Comment: I tried, thank you very much for your help... I think I have to start a course for Vue.js :) This is my codepen https://codepen.io/manlioma/pen/BEWQXm